# how to use hashcode in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flex3

Is it possible to use object.hashcode mwthod in flex 3? If so, how to use that (like object.hashcode or System.identityHashCode methods in java). Anybody come across this, please give me some samples. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no hashCode function defined on the [AS3 `Object` class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html).

More recent versions of `flash.utils` provide a [`Dictionary` class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html),which does provide a means to use an instance of an object as a *key*.  You could use this functionality to make an object registry, where you would assign unique keys to your objects.  Then you could make your own hash function to compute a hashcode on the unique key.

But if you're just ultimately trying to build a proper hashtable, you should just use the `Dictionary` instead of building your own.